# ¿Cómo puedo agrupar una lista en django de acuerdo a su categoría?

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-2.7, pandas

Estoy usando Django y la librería Pandas pero los datos no se me agrupan de acuerdo a su categoría. Dejo una imagen del resultado que obtengo:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que los productos de ese consolidado queden agrupados de acuerdo a su categoría, es decir, los productos de la categpría 'Margarita' deben quedar juntos, los de 'Bimbo' deben quedar juntos, etc.

Dejo por aquí el trozo de código que me genera este resultado:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lista_productos)
lista_productos_agrupados = df.groupby(("nombre", 
 "categoria")).sum().reset_index().to_dict(orient="records")
```

Agradezco su colaboración...

Comment: Estaría bien si pudieras proporcionar una muestra de los datos con los que trabajas (`lista_productos`) para poder probar a experimentar con tu código a ver en qué momento la agrupación se rompe o desordena. Podría ser por culpa del `.reset_index()`  o del `.to_dict()`.

Comment: Entiendo lo que me dices, otra solución que me serviría mucho es ordenar alfabéticamente esa lista de datos de acuerdo a su categoría, en vez de agruparlos. Aquí pongo un ejemplo de la lista de datos que estoy usando (No es la misma de la imagen):

Comment: **lista_productos = [{'nombre': 'Ducales', 'categoria': 'Noel', 'cantidad': 565}, {'nombre': 'Jumbo maní', 'categoria': 'Jet', 'cantidad': 262}, {'nombre': 'Papas BBQ', 'categoria': 'Margarita', 'cantidad': 350}, {'nombre': 'Papas de pollo', 'categoria': 'Margarita', 'cantidad': 92}, {'nombre': 'Papas natural', 'categoria': 'Margarita', 'cantidad': 612}, {'nombre': 'Pinguinos', 'categoria': 'Bimbo', 'cantidad': 265}]**

Comment: Agrego una solución a mi problema: **newlist = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: k['categoria'])**

Comment: Al agrupar por `('nombre','categoria')` buscas que te junte todos los del mismo nombre, y si hay varios nombres repetidos, esos los agrupe a su vez por categorías. Por tanto lo primero es el nombre, y ya que la tabla final la ordena por nombres, las categorías que aparezcan en diferentes nombres no tienen por qué salir seguidas. Quizás deberías entonces agrupar por `('categoria', 'nombre' )`